# While creating a Dataset for ADF sometimes we import Schema and sometimes we not. What is the reason behind it?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am creating a dataset of Azure blob storage type. While watching youtube videos of ADF i saw sometimes we import schema and sometimes we not
can you please guide me when we have to click on import schema

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add to what Chen said .
If you know that the your only focus is some few columns from source and there is a chance that your source can have few new columns in future , please go with mapping option . This saves from the any changes made on the source side .

If you want to make the pipeline more generic , please plan for going without mapping .

Answer (score 1):

If you import schema you can easily map columns in the mapping tab of copy activity. If you don't import schema, your dataset can be generic, and you can use it with different tables, without the need to create a dataset for each table.